# std::vector copy, what happens?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I would like to ask the community about std::vector, coming from C.

```
std::vector<int> temp1(4,0);
temp1[0] = 10;
std::vector<int> temp2;
temp2 = temp1;
temp1[0] = 0;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    std::cout<<"temp1: " <<temp1[i]<<"temp2: "<<temp2[i]<< std::endl;
```

temp1: 0    temp2: 10

temp1: 0    temp2: 0

temp1: 0    temp2: 0

temp1: 0    temp2: 0

at temp2 = temp1, temp2 appears to be a deep-copy, is this correct?  Also, what happens in this case?

```
std::vector<int> temp1(4,0);
std::vector<int> temp2(4,1);
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    // some temp2 values filled
    temp1 = temp2;
}
return 0;
```

when temp1 is updated, what actually happens.  Is a copy made and the previous temp1's destructor called?

Comment: Destructors are only called when an object's lifetime ends, e.g. when a local variable with automatic storage goes out of scope.

Comment: You know you can look this up pretty easily: [std::vector::operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)

Comment: `std::vector::operator=` does a deep copy.  Its one of the main reasons why `std::vector` is so generally useful.

Comment: If you really want to know what's going on when you do business with a vector, define a simple class that has logging (std::cout or so) in every constructor, destructor, copy constructor etc, then place those objects in the vector.

Comment: No research effort shown. These details are basic and can be found on the web or in your C++ book, trivially.

Comment: "deep-copy"? It is just an actual *copy*. Stuff gets *copied*. It is that simple."Shallow" copies aren't really copies.

Answer (score 1):

Because these objects are of type `std::vector<int>`, yes, it's a deep copy, but no, no destructor is called when you do `temp1 = temp2`.

If the type were `std::vector<X>` where `X` is a class, then
`temp1 = temp2` would still be a deep copy and 
(depending on further details of the two vectors and possibly the
implementation of std::vector)
it *might* destroy the
old *contents* of `temp1`--that is, whatever objects of type `X` were contained
in `temp1` before the assigment, their destructors might be called.
(The call to `std::vector<int>::operator=` *couldn't* call any destructors
because `int` has no destructor.)

If the type were `std::vector<*X>` (now `X` can be a class or `int` or some other primitive or even a pointer type), `temp1 = temp2` would not execute a deep copy--at least, *I* would not (usually) call it a deep copy, since only the pointers are copied and they point to the same objects as the pointers that are still in `temp2`.
(I say "usually" because there are some cases where someone 
can argue that the pointers themselves *are* the contents of the data structure
and therefore the copy is "deep".)
No destructor is called in this case, even if `X` is a class,
because `*X` does not have a destructor.

Comment: If the type were std::vector<X> where X is a class, then temp1 = temp2 would still be a deep copy , but it would call the class X copy constructor for each object of X contained in the temp1 container and i dont think the destructor for class X would be called  unless the temp1 container clear is called or goes out of scope

Comment: @Ram Good point. Cplusplus.com says, "Any elements held in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed." C++11 allows for the allocator to be replaced with a different allocator, in which case all contents are destroyed, but otherwise there does not seem to be a requirement to destroy contents. Another question is what happens if temp2.size() is much less than temp1.size(); could the std::vector reallocate to a smaller size to free memory?